# How to Reinstall missing apps and Packages after backup restored via deja dup backup tool in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup, restore

**Hi all,**

I have Ubuntu 20.04 and I made a backup via deja dup tool, choosing main /home directory. and then I wiped the whole disk and partition and re-install ubuntu 20.04 again.

After I restoration completed successfully, I saw only files restored, media, apps' data but there are many Ubuntu packages and apps missing, for example, MongoDB, vscode, openssh packages, all I have to reinstall them.

My questions

1. How I can reinstall missing packages and apps in short commands/steps? instead of doing it one by one although I cannot remember them.
2. Which other backup tools for ubuntu that restore the system as it exactly, I want even the appearance, customizations and wallpaper all become the same? Free tools, please.

**Thanks for your efforts and support,**

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use a tool that made an image of the whole disk, but that would defeat the purpose of reinstalling 20.04 from scratch.

Since many packages are installed at *root* level rather than in your home directory, you could back up *all* files on the disk, including essential system files. Again, if your object is to make a clean reinstallation of Ubuntu, by restoring everything, you'd defeat your purpose: you'd be back where you were before you started.

Perhaps the best choice would be to [list *all* packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages) on the machine before saving your home folder:

```
apt list --installed > ~/Desktop/packages.txt
```

Then wipe the disk, reinstall Ubuntu, and *again* list packages, **changing the output filename**. Compare the two lists and see which packages need to be reinstalled.

The [Synaptic Package Manager](https://itsfoss.com/synaptic-package-manager/) can handle installation from known PPA's, and the list of all packages can point you towards the source of the remainder.

[OSTechnix has a method to automate reinstallation](https://ostechnix.com/create-list-installed-packages-install-later-list-centos-ubuntu/), but, again, you'll need to know the PPA if not included in *Software & Updates*.